# Overwrite third party template file in my custom module

Tags: magento2, module, template, knockoutjs, third-party-module

I have done some research to this subject but couldn't seem to find a detailed answer.

**What I need**

To overwrite a template file from a third party module
*in my case: Amasty One Step Checkout*

Template file to overwrite:

> /app/code/Amasty/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage/shipping/methods.html

I have found that this file is loaded using knockoutjs via this function:

```
<!-- ko with: requestComponent('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress') -->
<!-- ko template: 'Amasty_Checkout/onepage/shipping/methods' --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

in file:

> app\code\Amasty\Checkout\view\frontend\web\template\onepage\3columns.html

**What I've done**

Added module dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Plugin_Name" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
            <module name="Amasty_Checkout" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Tried overwriting the template file like this in my module's *checkout_index_index.xml*

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress">
    <action method="setTemplate">
         <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Plugin_Name::shipping_view.html</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

But without success..

Can someone explain what steps to take to overwrite a third party's template file and if there is a difference if it is loaded in another template file via knockoutjs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Create `requirejs-config.js` file at below path.

```
/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

And put below code in requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Amasty_Checkout/template/onepage/shipping/methods.html': 
              'Vendor_Module/template/onepage/shipping/methods.html'
        }
  }
};
```

We can override any html file in this way.

Comment: What if we want to override a design template file to a custom module?